# Rails - passing randomly generated instance variable between routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, routes, instance-variables

I'm creating an app which randomly displays a "flashcard" for language practice, which the user needs to provide a translation to. I have two tables: Flashcards (containing the flashcard data) and Practices (for managing the practice sessions and storing the responses provided).

I have managed to get a flashcard to randomly display when the user starts a practice session but what I can't work out is how to set the code so that when a user provides the response, the program remembers/knows which random card has been displayed so it can correctly POST to Practices. My current code generates a new card between showing the card and saving it to the database as @flashcard doesn't persist between routes.

```
# practices_controller.rb

def index
  call_random
end

def create
  call_random
  @practice = Practice.create(practice_params.merge(session_id: @session_id, flashcard_id: @flashcard.id))
  if @practice.save
    redirect_to @practice
  else
    render 'index'
  end
end

def show
end

private

def find_practice
  @practice = Practice.find(params[:id])
end

def random_flashcard
  @flashcard = Flashcard.order("RANDOM()").first
end

def call_random
  @flashcard ||= random_flashcard
end
```

I've tried setting and reading class attributes and other private methods to try and save the randomly generated flashcard (either the whole object or the ID) but no solution has worked for me. One methods which I thought might get me close was this, but it still failed as @flashcards was still `nil` in the create route.

```
# practice_controller.rb

def index
  random_flashcard(:generate)
end

def create
  random_flashcard(:recall)
  @practice = Practice.create(practice_params.merge(session_id: @session_id, flashcard_id: @flashcard.id))
  if @practice.save
    redirect_to @practice
  else
    render 'index'
  end
end

private

def random_flashcard(action = :generate)
  if action == :generate
    @flashcard = Flashcard.order("RANDOM()").first
  elsif action == :recall
    @flashcard
  end
end
```

Comment: You have not made it clear what you're trying to do.  "So the program remembers" is not what actually happens.  Programs don't "remember" although they can store things in memory, but in your case, probably the database.  Try to explain what you need to happen in a code way.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Apologies. Let me try to explain better. I'd like the program to do the following:
0) The user creates a custom flashcard which they assign an "original" and "translation" value.
1) INDEX:
- Get a random flashcard from the Flashcard table.
- Show the "original" data column of the flashcard to the user so they have a phrase to translate.
2) CREATE:
- When the user submits their attempted translation, their attempt is saved in the Practice table.
3) SHOW:
- The user is shown the "original" and "translation" phrase of the random flashcard plus their input translation.
TBC...

Comment: It is the last bit that I'm struggling with - I cannot work out how to save the initial randomly-retrieved flashcard in step 1 (either the entire object or just the ID) so that it can be shown in step 3 as well. I hope that's clearer - sorry for not making it clear from the beginning. (FAO @lacostenycoder )

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept that you are missing is how the request/response cycle works.  There's plenty of information on this around the web, including the Rails Guides, so I'll keep this brief and simplified:

1. Your browser makes a request to your Rails application (a GET request would be something like "show me this URL" and a POST request would be something like "do this thing, represented by this URL, using the attached data").
2. Your application receives this request, the Rails router finds the appropriate controller/action, and your action does some stuff, and renders a template, which Rails helps turn into a response.
3. Your browser receives this HTML response and renders it in the browser.

That's it. HTTP is stateless.  By default, your application does not retain any state from request to request.  Have you ever seen 50 First Dates?  Web servers are basically Drew Barrymore's character, and each request is a day.  Your application remembers everything that happened in that request, but it starts with a clean slate on the next request with no memory of the last.  There are ways around this, such as persisting state in cookies, the URL, or form data, but you need to do that yourself.  By default, each request has no connection to the last.

In your case, you are dealing with two requests.  The first is a GET to your `index`, the second is a POST to your `create` action.  Each request results in a new controller instance being instantiated, with fresh state.  Your application - by default - sees no connection between those two requests.  Is the create action always invoked after the index?  Your application doesn't known or care.  That's up to you, the developer.

I think you are expecting your `@flashcard` variable to persist between your initial `index` request and the subsequent POST to `create`.  But imagine how that'd work with multiple users.  Two users load the index, then user A posts to `create` followed by user B.  How would the application differentiate them?  How would it know which flashcard each was viewing?  Well, that's up to you.

There are a few ways to go about persisting state between requests - you'll often see long-term state tracked as part of the "session" (a cookie), which is beyond the scope of the answer - but I'd encourage you to read up on them, as they are immensely important in web development.

However, for short-term state - such as persisting state between a single request -> response -> request - especially when the last request is a form POST - you can use a form field - and that's exactly how I'd solve your problem.

1. Don't set a random flashcard in your `create` action.
2. Add a `flashcard_id` **hidden** field to the form you are rendering in your `index`.
3. When that form is submitted, your `create` action will receive the `flashcard_id` param.  Use that ID to create your `Practice` record.

In plain english, the way this works is:  Your user requests the page with the random flashcard (GET `index`). Your application responds with some HTML that will display the flashcard, along with a hidden field containing its ID.  The user submits the form, triggering a new request (POST `create`), and the flashcard's ID is sent back to the server as part of that request's form data.  Your application receives this request, expects this ID to be included in the form data (in the `params` hash, in Rails), and creates the `Practice` using that ID.